# Save System.Windows.Forms.Keys as Setting

Tags: c#, settings, key

I'm making a program that uses hotkeys for various things. 
These hotkeys will be user-settable, and thus it'd be nice if those would be saved on exit.
Since the amount of keys on a keyboard is pretty large (including the OEM keys and such), I don't feel much warmth towards a huge monstrosity of IF clausules.

I tried using the builtin settings thingamajigg (Properties.Settings.Default etc) But it doesn't seem to save the keys properly. (That or I'm doing something wrong.)

This is the code I'm using for that right now:

```
// (..some code ommitted) 
if (comboBox_hotkeys_uploadclipboard_modifier.SelectedText != "" && comboBox_hotkeys_uploadclipboard_key.SelectedText != "")
{
    if (comboBox_hotkeys_uploadclipboard_modifier.SelectedText == "None")
        Properties.Settings.Default.hotkeys_uploadclipboard_modifier = 0;
    else
        Properties.Settings.Default.hotkeys_uploadclipboard_modifier = modifierdict[comboBox_hotkeys_uploadclipboard_modifier.SelectedText];
    Properties.Settings.Default.hotkeys_uploadclipboard_key = keydict[comboBox_hotkeys_uploadclipboard_key.SelectedText];
}
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
return true;
```

And at the beginning of the program i do:

```
Dictionary<string, uint> modifierdict = new Dictionary<string, uint>();
Dictionary<string, Keys> keydict = new Dictionary<string, Keys>();

public Form_stuff()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Enum.GetNames(typeof(ModifierKeysH)).Length; i++)
    {
        modifierdict.Add(Enum.GetNames(typeof(ModifierKeysH))[i], (uint)Enum.GetValues(typeof(ModifierKeysH)).GetValue(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Enum.GetNames(typeof(Keys)).Length; i++)
    {
        keydict.Add(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Keys))[i], (Keys)Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)).GetValue(i));
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't seem to actually save the keys, or load them on the next program launch. (yes I have code in place for that part too)

Does anyone know a(n easy) way?

EDIT:

Here's the code i use for setting the hotkeys, without the interop parts etc, those are hosted elsewhere in the code:

```
    public void SetKeyboardHooks()
    {
        if (!(kbhook == null))
            kbhook.Dispose();
        kbhook = new KeyboardHook();
        //Set clipboard upload hotkey
        kbhook.RegisterHotKey((ModifierKeysH)Properties.Settings.Default.hotkeys_uploadclipboard_modifier, Properties.Settings.Default.hotkeys_uploadclipboard_key);
        kbhook.KeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs>(kbhook_KeyPressed);
    }

    void kbhook_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifier == (ModifierKeysH)Properties.Settings.Default.hotkeys_uploadclipboard_modifier && e.Key == Properties.Settings.Default.hotkeys_uploadclipboard_key)
        {
            string url = Functions.UploadClipboard();
            Clipboard.SetText(url);
            hificon.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Upload succesful!", "Uploaded to: " + url,ToolTipIcon.Info);
        }
    }
```

As you can see the code is far from finished. This is just a roadblock here i'm trying to overcome..
The main thing that doesn't seem to be working is the fact that the hotkeys don't actually get SAVED. settings doesn't seem to like System.Windows.Forms.Keys, and then also skips the ModifierkeysH part, which are saved as uint.

Comment: What are you doing exactly? Does your app have a certain amount of hotkeys that the user can map to different actions or does your app have a certain amount of actions that the user can map to the hotkeys he wishes?

Comment: The app has a certain amount of actions -- Upload clipboard contents, make screenshot, etc. It's a very much zscreen inspired app, except much lighter and less extensive. The user then maps a hotkey to each action. The program has to remember those hotkeys then afterwards. I'll add some more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm people, it works just like it should, except for some reason the Comboboxes didn't return a value with .SelectedValue, instead you have to use .SelectedItem for some reason. 
In any case, it works flawlessly now. thanks for everyone's time and may this thread slap someone in the face in the future for not using .SelectedItem .